# Converting C variables into JSON Format

Tags: c, json

I need a  C program where my C string variables need to be converted into JSON string variables. The string variables I have in my C program are:
    char mcode[20]="123456"

```
billno[20]="0057",customerId[10]="8989898",name[20]="abc",details[20]={"FMCG","90000"};
float total=135000;
```

And I want the above values to be converted into JSON code as shown in below format:

```
{ 
  "mcode":"123456" ,
    "bill": {
        "no": "0057",
        "customerId": "8989898",
        "name":"abc", 
        "details": [{"category":"FMCG","amount":90000},   {"category":"Electronics","amount":45000}]
    },
    "total":135000 
}
```

Help me in finding the code in C.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't put up any code to show how you are trying (and failing) to JSON encode those variables.

All I can suggest is a C library such as http://www.digip.org/jansson/ to handle that side of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of useful resources at the bottom of the [JSON format home page](http://json.org/).